# How to handle database scalability with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql

I am creating a management system and I want to know how "**Ruby on Rails**" can support me in the mission of **ensuring that each customer has their information, records and tables independent from other customers**.

Is it better to put everything in a database and put a customer identifier to pull information through this parameter in queries or **create a database for each customer automatically?**

I admit that **the second option attracts me more** ... And I know that **putting everything in one database will be detrimental to performance**, because **I assume that customers and their data will increase exponentially**!

**I want to know which option is more viable in the long run**. And if the best option is to create separate databases, **how can I do this** with **Ruby on Rails** ??

Comment: What do you mean with a `bank`? Why do you assume it will increase exponentially?

Comment: database! Sorry for this poorly exemplified inflection

Comment: I'm starting from the point that there will be a lot of people signing up and will grow soon ...

Comment: Every app developer thinks that! Exponential grow is very rare. Stay realistic, build a solid app and deal with scaling issues when you really hit them.

Comment: I don't want to slow down your ambitions but the sooner you will get 'exponential growth' out of your head the better. 99.9999% of the time this does not happen. Dont pre optimise your app, spend your energy on building a solid app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are pro and cons for both solutions which really depend on your use case.

Separating each customer in its own database has definitely advantages for scaling, running in different data centres or even onsite. However, this comes with higher complexity. For instance you can't query across customers anymore, you would need to run queries for each customers and aggregate the results. This approach is called multi tenancy (or shardening). There is a good gem called Apartment available (https://github.com/influitive/apartment).

Keeping everything in one database might be simpler to start of as it's less complex but it really depends on your use case.

### Edit

Adding some more information based on the questions.

There are several reasons to use a one db per client architecture.

1. You have clearly separated tenants. In case it might make sense to go with the one db approach.
2. Scale. Having separated databases for each tenant makes scaling of course easier.

If 2) is the main reason you want to go for a one db per client approach I would strongly advise you against it. You add so much more complexity to your app which you might not need for years to come (if ever).

If scaling is your main concern I recommend reading [Designing Data Intensive Applications](https://dataintensive.net/) by Martin Kleppmann. But basically, don't worry about scale for the first few years and focus on your product.

Comment: I didn't know this gem and I knew little about tenants' concepts. I will study this further, I saw a tutorial from "Go Rails" that talks about the subject. Thanks for the clear and straightforward explanation. I think that ends my doubt, but I still want to hear other opinions!

Comment: Sure. With the little information provided nobody really can give you a good recommendation. Most of the time you're better off without multi tenancy though.

Comment: Do you think that worrying about the poor performance of a database is foolish in most cases? At what point should we start to worry about this, that is, at numerical levels. How many rows in the database to cause this type of bottleneck?

Comment: Edited my answer. Foolish is strong word but yes I think if scale is your only reason why you want to go with a one db per client architecture then I think it's not a very good reason.

Comment: I'm thinking about security, imagine a user of client A seeing information from client B. Well done queries solve this, but do you think that would be a plausible reason? Please, friend, explain more about what would be a good reason

Comment: This is a concern for every app and not really related to multi tenancy. If you have a proper test suite, both solutions should be secure.